# Light-hole and heavy-hole bands: Which is which?

Tags: mass, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I am currently studying *Introductory Semiconductor Device Physics* by Parker. Chapter **2.5 The concept of effective mass** describes the *light-hole* and *heavy-hole* valence band in figure 2.8(b):

> [image]

The author then poses the question: Which is which?

Since we have that $m^* = \dfrac{\hbar^2}{d^2E/dk^2}$, where $m^*$ is the effective mass, it seemed reasonable to me that the inner band, which has greater curvature, would be the light-hole band, since we are dividing the reduced Planck constant by a larger value, resulting in a smaller magnitude, and the outer band, which has less curvature, would be the heavy-hole band, since we are dividing the reduced Planck constant by a smaller value, resulting in a larger magnitude. Is my assessment correct? I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to review my reasoning here.

Comment: Your reasoning looks sound to me.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct: the heavy-hole band is the one where the electrons have greater mass, i.e. the one having smaller curvature (since curvature is roughly the inverse mass).

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Please do not edit MathJax into posts to format things that are not formulae. Whether or not a reference to an equation like "eq. (2)" should be MathJax or not is at best a stylistic choice. Don't use your edit privileges to impose your style preferences upon others.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: No, I am not imposing my style upon others. I just improved format for better readability and understanding. That's it. If you don't like that you can remove my edits I won't mind it.

Comment: Thank you both for the review.